# HTML E-mail form

Tags: html

So my site is almost done but I'm stuck on the part of sending an email.
Everything works, when I fill in the fields. But it always gets saved as a draft so I don't receive the email.
Here is my html code:
This code is copied from a site.

```html
<form action="mailto:myemailadress@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: You can't send an e-mail with HTML. You can only trigger the client's default mail application to open with some of the information pre-filled.

Comment: @Santi Is this possible with a bit of php ?

Comment: Yep, you'll need some sort of server-side language like PHP to actually send an email. There should be a bunch of tutorials out there for that. If you're using a host like GoDaddy you can use their SMTP server, otherwise you can look into services like ElasticEmail. MailChimp, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**action="mailto:myemailadress@gmail.com"** <-- This is not correct.

You'll have to point your post submission to a handler php file that will process the form request and submit the email.

Now, some host providers do have a php mailer to make us things easier, e.g godaddy https://www.godaddy.com/es/help/using-our-php-form-mailers-on-web-and-classic-hosting-8376 .

An example of php mail handler for forms can be found here http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php . It has some validation code too.

There is a possibility that you're using a server that doesn't support PHP but ASP, .NET, Node.js or some other, in that case i can't help you because i'm not familiar to none of them :)

Comment: That can be **another** problem. If your apache server doesn't have php-lib extension loaded, php fgci, or your machine isn't running PHP-FPM, you won't be able to process your php mail handler file.